# Opening NSURL using string variable - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I have a variable called storedURL which is in the format `www.xxxxx.com`. I am trying to use the below code to open this URL in Safari when a user clicks a button.

```
-(IBAction)launchWeb {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",
                     storedURL];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];  
}
```

However the app crashes when the button is clicked.

Can anyone help correct my code ?

EDIT

mvds' code crashes with following :

2011-04-02 14:01:41.542 London[16791:207] +[NSURL urlWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103dcbc
2011-04-02 14:01:41.545 London[16791:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL urlWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103dcbc'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fd95a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0112d313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fdb17b +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f4a966 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f4a522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   London                        0x00006bce -[DetailViewController launchWeb] + 126
    6   UIKit                               0x0022b4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    7   UIKit                               0x002bb799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x002bdc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    9   UIKit                               0x002bc7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    10  UIKit                               0x004be4de _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 3609
    11  UIKit                               0x004bec53 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 927
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00fba89b **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00f4f6e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00f181d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f17840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f17761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0151a1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0151a289 GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x00239c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  London                        0x00001ee9 main + 121
    21  London                        0x00001e65 start + 53

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URL is probably `nil`, since "www.xxxxxxx.com" is not a url. Try

```
 NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/",storedURL];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
 NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

If this doesn't help, please share the output (stack trace) given in the console window.

Comment: Hi mvds. Thanks for your help. This code crashes with stack above. There is also a warning that NSURL my not respond to urlWithString.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco, fix the case on the method URLWithString.  That will take of this issue.

Comment: Still crashing at first line :NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/",storedURL];

Comment: Nothing in output (stack trace). Just gives reason "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: solved - storedURL was being lost as it needed retaining - THANK YOU